# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application - in cmd

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I built my javafx project in a jar file. When I try to run it in cmd, I get an error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application. But in my development program - Intellij IDEA, when the program starts, everything is fine.

Comment: If you created a fat/uber/shaded JAR file (i.e., a JAR-with-dependencies), then JavaFX is being placed on the class-path, which is not a supported configuration.  However, you can make it work, but your main class _cannot_ inherit from `javafx.application.Application`; you'll need a separate main class that simply launches JavaFX.

Comment: If you did not create a fat JAR file, then you presumably have JavaFX elsewhere on your computer. You have to add JavaFX to the module-path in that case. Unless you have a JDK with JavaFX included (you very likely don't).

Comment: Deploying JavaFX applications as an executable JAR is not the preferred approach. You should consider deploying a "self-contained" application. This can be accomplished with `jlink` + `jpackage` (or other tools). See the "Packaging" section in the [JavaFX tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for more information.